# Power Apps, Pen Input to Sharepoint List

Tags: powerapps

If anyone could help it would really be appreciated I am struggling to find out how to store my Pen Input image into my Sharepoint List, I dont seem to be able to find any instructions on how to carry this out.

I have found a lot of information telling me that this hasnt been developed as of yet but these posts where back in 2016 so Im unsure if this is still the case.

I am creating a registration form and a signature field is required, but I cant keep the information in a gallery as I cant have the information stored at device level.

But I need to be able to see the signatures within my Sharepoint list against the other information I am collecting.

Thanks

Paula

Comment: Paula - This is the best solution I have found: https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/flow-en/powerapps-hand-written-signature/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method:

https://hatfullofdata.blog/powerapps-using-json-function-to-save-pictures/

This is for multiple pictures, but the idea is the same.

1. Use the Parse JSON action in a Power Automate flow to receive, decode and save the pictures to SharePoint
2. Use the JSON() function in PowerApps to convert the image to base64, and then call the flow (sending the converted results as a parameter).